# Установка Хакинтош и как решить его проблемы

Tags: mac

Всем доброго времени суток! Уже почти неделю пытаюсь установить хакинтош, но пока безрезультатно. Точнее результаты есть, но не те, которые мне нужны. Люди, помогите, кто в этом разбирается!!! Очень надо!!! 
И так, я могу поставить хакинтош на виртуальную машину, точнее у мне даже две версии стоит (EL Capitan и Yosemite, обе рабочие, запускаются, но есть одно НО...) и у меня собственно несколько проблем, которые я никак не могу решить или найти их решение в Интернете.

1) В обоих случаях у меня ВСЕГДА отображается, что видеопамять 128МБ, хотя в настройках ставлю больше (256-512). Не особо может и критично, но все же.

2) Yosemite работает лучше, чем EL Capitan, т.е. не тормозит жестко, как EL Capitan. EL Capitan дико тормозит... ка бы это исправить?

3) Yosemite работает стабильно и не зависает, пока  я не начну работать в XCode. После 5-10 (редко 15) минут работы система тупо зависает и помогает только выключение.

Уже все делал, и настройки в БИОСе менял, и всякие там проги ставил, и ядро менял, и с флешки устанавливал... Уже не знаю что и как... Но очень надо установить Хакинтош

Answer (score 0):

Приведите конфигурацию оборудования, опишите какие модули/параметры использовали. Без этого подсказать вам что-то вряд ли смогут.

Опубликуйте ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports и ~\Library\Logs\CloverEFI

Comment: Характеристики моего ПК:
Мат. плата GA-870A-USB3L
Процессор AMD Athlon(tm) II X4 640 Processor, 3000 МГц
Видеокарта    Имя NVIDIA GeForce GTX 650
Оператива     8ГБ

Comment: ~\Library\Logs\CloverEFI - такого нет

~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports - несколько файлов есть, и есть еще 3 файла с пометкой "Crash", но их не могу никак скопировать и отправить.